# How to replace every other instance of a particular character in a MySQL string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, replace

How to replace value in mysql column by query like, Column is `options` and its of type `varchar(255)`

From

```
id   options
1    A|10|B|20|C|30
2    A|Positive|B|Negative
```

To

```
id   options
1    A|10,B|20,C|30
2    A|Positive,B|Negative
```

I am doing it by php like this.

```
<?php
    $str =  "A|10|B|20|C|30";
    $arr = explode("|",$str);
    $newArr = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i+=2){
      if($arr[$i] && $arr[$i+1]){
        $newArr[] = $arr[$i]."|".$arr[$i+1];
      }
    }
    echo "Before:".$str."\n";
    echo "After :".implode(",",$newArr);
?>
```

https://eval.in/841007

So instead of PHP, I want to do this in MySQL.

Comment: So instead of PHP, you want to do this in MySQL?

Comment: yes      please, you got the point, I am copying you comment in my question

Comment: Please show us the schema.

Comment: Column is `options` and its of type `varchar(255)`

Comment: So you want to change a table with 6 columns into a table with 4 columns???

Comment: Ok, let me re-phrase. Where is `A` coming from? Where is `10` coming from? Are they in different columns? What query have you used already?

Comment: I just copied data where one column has with these type of data, I want to convert as I described in one same column named `options`

Comment: @RiggsFolly : I update my question

Comment: @MilanChheda :  : I update my question

Answer (score 7):

You should consider to store your data in a normalized schema. In your case the table should look like:

```
| id | k |        v |
|----|---|----------|
|  1 | A |       10 |
|  1 | B |       20 |
|  1 | C |       30 |
|  2 | A | Positive |
|  2 | B | Negative |
```

This schema is more flexible and you will see why.

So how to convert the given data into the new schema? You will need a helper table containing sequence numbers. Since your column is `varchar(255)` you can only store 128 values (+ 127 delimiters) in it. But let's just create 1000 numbers. You can use any table with enough rows. But since any MySQL server has the `information_schema.columns` table, I will use it.

```
drop table if exists helper_sequence;
create table helper_sequence (i int auto_increment primary key)
    select null as i
    from information_schema.columns c1
    join information_schema.columns c2
    limit 1000;
```

We will use this numbers as position of the values in your string by joining the two tables.

To extract a value from a delimited string you can use the `substring_index()` function. The value at position `i` will be

```
substring_index(substring_index(t.options, '|', i  ), '|', -1)
```

In your string you have a sequence of keys followed by its values. The position of a key is an odd number. So if the position of the key is `i`, the position of the corresponding value will be `i+1`

To get the number of the delimiters in the string and limit our join we can use

```
char_length(t.options) - char_length(replace(t.options, '|', ''))
```

The query to store the data in a normalized form would be:

```
create table normalized_table
    select t.id
        , substring_index(substring_index(t.options, '|', i  ), '|', -1) as k
        , substring_index(substring_index(t.options, '|', i+1), '|', -1) as v
    from old_table t
    join helper_sequence s
      on s.i <= char_length(t.options) - char_length(replace(t.options, '|', ''))
    where s.i % 2 = 1
```

Now run `select * from normalized_table` and you will get this:

```
| id | k |        v |
|----|---|----------|
|  1 | A |       10 |
|  1 | B |       20 |
|  1 | C |       30 |
|  2 | A | Positive |
|  2 | B | Negative |
```

So why is this format a better choice? Besides many other reasons, one is that you can easily convert it to your old schema with

```
select id, group_concat(concat(k, '|', v) order by k separator '|') as options
from normalized_table
group by id;

| id |               options |
|----|-----------------------|
|  1 |        A|10|B|20|C|30 |
|  2 | A|Positive|B|Negative |
```

or to your desired format

```
select id, group_concat(concat(k, '|', v) order by k separator ',') as options
from normalized_table
group by id;

| id |               options |
|----|-----------------------|
|  1 |        A|10,B|20,C|30 |
|  2 | A|Positive,B|Negative |
```

If you don't care about normalization and just want this task to be done, you can update your table with

```
update old_table o
join (
    select id, group_concat(concat(k, '|', v) order by k separator ',') as options
    from normalized_table
    group by id
) n using (id)
set o.options = n.options;
```

And drop the `normalized_table`.

But then you won't be able to use simple queries like

```
select *
from normalized_table
where k = 'A'
```

See [demo at rextester.com](http://rextester.com/DCG62096)

Answer (score 3):

Not using stored procedures, I would do it in 2 steps:

1. Insert the comma at the second occurrence of the pipe character:

   ```sql
   update options set options = insert(options, locate('|', options, locate('|', options) + 1), 1, ',');
   ```
2. Insert the remaining commas - execute the query N times:

   ```sql
   update options set options = insert(options, locate('|', options, locate('|', options, length(options) - locate(',', reverse(options)) + 1) + 1), 1, ',');
   ```

   where N =

   ```sql
   select max(round(((length(options) - length(replace(options, '|', ''))) - 1 ) / 2) - 1) from options;
   ```

   (or don't bother with counting and continue to execute the query as long as it doesn't tell you "0 rows affected")

Checked with this set of data:

```
id   options
1    A|10|B|20|C|30
2    A|Positive|B|Negative
3    A|10|B|20|C|30|D|40|E|50|F|60
4    A|Positive|B|Negative|C|Neutral|D|Dunno
```

results in:

```sql
id   options
1    A|10,B|20,C|30
2    A|Positive,B|Negative
3    A|10,B|20,C|30,D|40,E|50,F|60
4    A|Positive,B|Negative,C|Neutral,D|Dunno
```

---

(I'll provide an explanation later)

Answer (score 3):

**Demo**

[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/NEQ7295)

**Explanation**

This could be solved relatively easily if only MySQL had a regular expression replacement function but [unfortunately it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826). So [I wrote one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826#38660574) - see [this blog post](http://stevettt.blogspot.com/2018/02/a-mysql-regular-expression-replace.html). The "advanced version" is needed here to allows it to perform a recursive replace in the found match for the replacement. Then the following relatively simple SQL can be used:

**SQL *(function code omitted for brevity)***

```
SELECT id,
       options AS `before`,
       reg_replace(options,
                   '\\|.*\\|', -- 2 pipe symbols with any text in between
                   '\\|$',     -- Replace the second pipe symbol
                   ',',        -- Replace with a comma
                   FALSE,      -- Non-greedy matching
                   2,          -- Min match length = 2 (2 pipe symbols)
                   0,          -- No max match length
                   0,          -- Min sub-match length = 1 (1 pipe symbol)
                   0           -- Max sub-match length = 1 (1 pipe symbol)
                   ) AS `after`
FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hum, I think you are trying to do something like this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(options,",") SEPARATOR "|") FROM Table.name;
```

I explain briefly, I take for each row the result and I concatenate "," and I concatenate all the row with the separator "|".
You will have to change the Table.name with the name of your table

If you want to concatenate one more value like A,B,C (you did not explain from where the ABC value are coming from so let's say ValueWhereABCisComingFrom):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ValueWhereABCisComingFrom,"|",options) SEPARATOR ",") FROM Table.name;
```

if my table is like this :

```
id | ValueWhereABCisComingFrom | options
0  | A    | 10
1  | B    | 20
2  | C    | 30
```

You wil have something like that :

```
A|10,B|20,C|30
```

**EDIT 1**

There is no way to do that in that case. There is no function like preg_replace in mysql. All you can do is to replace all the "|" like

```
SELECT  Replace(options, '|', ',') AS P
FROM `docs`;
```

In MariaDB, there is such a function so you could maybe try to pass from one base to an other. But with MYSQL only, no way :/

Comment: I have edit my answer but I'm sorry to say that, there is no way to do that in MySQL only.

Answer (score 2):

You can do by creating a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION doiterate(str TEXT, i INT, next INT, isp TINYINT(1))
  RETURNS TEXT
  BEGIN
    myloop: LOOP
      IF next = 0 THEN
        LEAVE myloop;
      END IF;
      IF isp = TRUE THEN
        set str = insert(str, i, 1, ',');
        set isp = FALSE;
        set i = next;
        set next = locate('|', str, i + 1);
        ITERATE myloop;
      ELSE
        set isp = TRUE;
        set i = next;
        set next = locate('|', str, i + 1);
        ITERATE myloop;
      END IF;
      LEAVE myloop;
    END LOOP;
    return str;
  END;
```

and calling it that way :

```
SELECT t.`column`,
  @loc := locate('|', t.`column`) as position,
  @next := locate('|', t.`column`, @loc +1) as next,
  @isp := 0 is_pipe,
  @r := doiterate(t.column, @loc, @next, @isp) as returnstring
from test t;
```

I assume you'll be smart enough to

- change the tablename & column name
- insert this into an update request

You can change the @isp := to 1 if I got the wrong pipe/coma change (i assumed second pipe should be changed to a coma)