# How can I split a string by ; and store in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, split

I have 2 tables

```
tbl_patient 
pid       sample_id    fullname             test_ivd
 1        AA01         John Vick            test 1; test 2; test 3
```

and

```
tbl_test
tid         sample_id    name_test
 1          AA01         test 1
 2          AA01         test 2
 3          AA01         test 3
```

When I add a new record (new patient) into tbl_patient, I stored one string separated by ; (list of test names) in test_ivd field. And in same time, I want to split the test_ivd by ; and add to the 3 new records in tbl_test. So please give me some suggestion.

Thank for any suggestion.

Comment: check this  : https://stackoverflow.com/q/45478226/2815635

Comment: Why would you want to store the data in such a redundant way? That only increases the potential for stuff to go wrong, if updating the one succeeds and the other fails ... You should rather use proper JOINs to get this data from the tbl_test table when needed.

Comment: @user2486 How is that question related? He doesn't need to alternate delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

use explode: explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )
http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest handling that with php.

1. Insert patient into database
2. retrieve inserted id
3. Insert tests into test table for retrieved id (you can write your query to insert sample_id of your patient instead of its id)

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
$string = "chicken;lamb;beef";
$stuff = explode(";", $string);
print_r($stuff);

//access by $stuff[0], $stuff[1] etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `PHP explode` function.

```
$ivdString = 'test 1; test 2; test 3';
$strArr = explode(";", $ivdString);
```

For insert record.

```
foreach ($strArr as $key => $value) {
      $sql = INSERT into table(sample_id,name_test)values('', '$value');
      Your insert here ...
      ......
}
```